# How to align the label filed of a css only material design select option

Tags: html, css

I have a css only google material select/dropdown.The select label  works fine when the select is a "required" filed.

```
<select class="select-text" required>.
```

If the "required" removed from the select the label shifts to the top ( `css ~:valid` ). How to css the label for a non required filed to match with the default style with out having any js.?

Comment: Eg: https://codepen.io/arun-harshan/pen/zVYvdg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the select isn't required, you need to change the CSS rule

`.select-text:focus ~ .select-label, .select-text:valid ~ .select-label`

to

`.select-text ~ .select-label`